# Required error messages based on label in html?

Tags: java, properties, internationalization, wicket

I try to i18n a WicketApplication that uses forms, and labels.

I use Wicket 7.3.0, running from the maven-quickstart in jetty.

I would like the Feedback message to use the `label` contents, but now it uses the field-name. I remember seeing this working sometime in the past, but it seems not to work now. Maybe I relied on an edge-case. Anyway, my question is if this is the 'proper' way, or if not, what I should do differently.

This is my (test-case) code:

### HTML

```
<body>
    <div wicket:id="fp"></div>
    <form wicket:id="f">
        <table>
        <tr><td><label wicket:for="naam"><wicket:message key="Naam"></wicket:message></label></td><td><input wicket:id="naam" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label wicket:for="adres"><wicket:message key="Adres"></wicket:message></label></td><td><input wicket:id="adres" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><label wicket:for="woonplaats"><wicket:message key="Woonplaats"></wicket:message></label></td><td><input wicket:id="woonplaats"/></td></tr>
        </table>
        <a wicket:id="save">Save!</a>
    </form>
</body>
```

### Java

```
public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {
        super(parameters);
        final FeedbackPanel fp = new FeedbackPanel("fp");
        fp.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        this.add(fp);
        Form f = new Form<Void>("f") {
        };
        f.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        f.add(new TextField("naam", Model.of("Rob")).setRequired(true));
        f.add(new TextField("adres", Model.of("Fantasieweg 4")));
        f.add(new TextField("woonplaats", Model.of("Babbelerdam")).setRequired(true));
        // TODO Add your page's components here
        f.add(new AjaxSubmitLink("save", f) {
            @Override
            protected void onAfterSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
                target.add(fp);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                target.add(fp);
            }
        });
        this.add(f);
    }
```

### WicketApplication.properties

```
Required=Veld ${label} is verplicht
Naam=PropertyNaam
Adres=PropertyAdres
Woonplaats=PropertyWoonplaats
```

Comment: Shouldn't Naam=PropertyNaam be naam=PropertyNaam (note the lowercase first character of the key) ?

Comment: @svenmeier not sure if it is required.. The resulting HTML has the translated values in the labels, so I assumed that was OK.

Comment: The translated values are shown in the labels because you're using "Naam" (uppercase) there :P.

Comment: Ah ok. I assumed using the label construction somehow made the getLabel() of the associated FormComponent return the translated value. Guess I was wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to `setlabel` for your component like this:

```
    ...
    f.add(new TextField("naam", Model.of("Rob")).setRequired(true).setLabel(YOUR_COMPONENT_LABEL));
    ...
```